# VBA Beginner - searching a row for a specific value then count it

Tags: vba, excel

I am relatively new to VBA and I am learning as I go, so my scripting probably isn't the best solution to the problem at hand.  I have a range of cells which I need to check a row of three columns for an occurrence of a string/value, if it appears at least once within the row of three columns then I need to add a count this, if not then I need to look for the next option which is another value, if that appears more than once count this occurrence and then finally check for the last option and add a count to that.  I want to then print the counts to a cell within the work sheet.

Unfortunately I wont know what the first row and last row number I will be searching is so I have a bit of script which will tell me these and assign to an integer, I know this works.  What doesn't work is the second part where I am searching the rows and looking for the value and adding a count.  It does print to the worksheet but all I get it three 0's.

I am not sure where in my code has gone wrong - compiles fine with no errors.

This is the scripting I have: -

```
Public Sub counts()

    Dim redVarCount As Integer
    Dim amberVarCount As Integer
    Dim greenVarCount As Integer

    'Used to find the first and last occurrence of the type want to count colors for
    mediumStartRow = Range("H:H").Find(what:="Medium", after:=Range("H21")).Row
    mediumEndRow = Range("H:H").Find(what:="Medium", after:=Range("H21"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    MsgBox "First and Last Row for Medium Projects: " & mediumStartRow & mediumEndRow

    redVar = "Red Variance" 'This is the value I am looking for in the row - Red Variance
    amberVar = "Amber Variance" 'this is the value I am looking for in the row - Amber Variance
    greenVar = "Green Variance" 'This is the value I am looking for in the row - Green Variance

    redVarCount = 0
    amberVarCount = 0
    greenVarCount = 0

    For Each Row In Range("AS" & mediumStartRow & ":AU" & mediumEndRow)
        If Row.Value2 = redVar > 0 Then
            redVarCount = redVarCount + 1
            Else
            If Row.Value2 = amberVar > 0 Then
                amberVarCount = amberVarCount + 1
                Else
                If Row.Value2 = greenVar > 0 Then
                    greenVarCount = greenVarCount + 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Range("DO22").Value = redVarCount
    Range("DO23").Value = amberVarCount
    Range("DO24").Value = greenVarCount

End Sub
```

Can anyone tell me where I have gone wrong or a better way of doing this please

Edit 1

Here is an example of the data

```
Medium  Green   Red Amber       Counts for medium   
medium  Green   Green   Green       Green   1
medium  Amber   Green   Green       Amber   1
large   Green   Amber   Amber       Red 1
large   Red Green   Green           
small   Amber   Amber   Amber           
small   Green   Green   Green           
small   Green   Green   Amber           
small   Green   Amber   Green
```

Once I can get it working for the mediums I will be doing it for the Large and Small.

Comment: Completely unrelated to your question.  A big piece of advice I can give you as a self taught VBA scripter is reduce your tab spacing to 2.  It will make things so much easier to read when you go back and look at code you wrote 2+ years ago.  Also comments, you can never have enough comments.  This will stop the you from now wanting to build a time machine to punch the you from 2 years ago in the face.

Comment: Also `For Each Row In Range` it's probably not a good idea to use `Row`. If you wanted to get the row number of Row it wouldn't make for good readability if it would work at all. `myLong = Row.row 'insert boat here `

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way of counting the number of occurences of each of the variables you put into `DO22:DO24` would be to simply put a `COUNTIF`-function into them:

```
Dim sAddress As String
Set sAddress = "AS" & mediumStartRow & ":AU" & mediumEndRow
(...)
Range("DO22").Formula = "=COUNTIF(" & sAddress & "," & redVar & ")"
Range("DO23").Formula = "=COUNTIF(" & sAddress & "," & amberVar & ")"
Range("DO24").Formula = "=COUNTIF(" & sAddress & "," & greenVar & ")"
```

If you want the cells to be numbers and not formulas, you can use worksheetfunctions inside of macros as well:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim redVar As String

Set r = Range("AS" & mediumStartRow & ":AU" & mediumEndRow)
redVar = "Red Variance"
redVarCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r, redVar)

etc.
```

If you want a review of your original code, which I definitely think could use some improvements, feel free to say so in the comments. As it is I don't feel like trying to track down your bug when I don't have your source data, and your code is a bit convoluted to read, unless you really want to know where you've gone wrong.

**- edit -**
After you expanding about your problems a bit, it is clear that the above solution won't work. I hacked together the following macro, which isn't very elegant, but should get the job done. Please contact me if you have any questions.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub counts()
  Dim redVarCount   As Long
  Dim amberVarCount As Long
  Dim greenVarCount As Long
  Dim i             As Long
  Dim mediumStart   As Range
  Dim mediumEnd     As Range
  Dim r             As Range
  Dim redVar        As String
  Dim amberVar      As String
  Dim greenVar      As String
  Dim amberFound    As Boolean
  Dim greenFound    As Boolean


  'Used to find the first and last occurrence of the type want to count colors for
  Set mediumStart = Range("H:H").Find(What:="Medium", After:=Range("H20"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
  Set mediumEnd = Range("H:H").Find(What:="Medium", After:=Range("H20"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

  If Not mediumStart Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "First and Last Row for Medium Projects: " & mediumStart.Row & " & " & mediumEnd.Row

    redVar = "Red Variance" 'This is the value I am looking for in the row - Red Variance
    amberVar = "Amber Variance" 'this is the value I am looking for in the row - Amber Variance
    greenVar = "Green Variance" 'This is the value I am looking for in the row - Green Variance

    redVarCount = 0
    amberVarCount = 0
    greenVarCount = 0
    amberFound = False
    greenFound = False

    For Each r In Range("AS" & mediumStart.Row & ":AS" & mediumEnd.Row)
      For i = 0 To 2
        Debug.Print r.Offset(0, i).Address
        If r.Offset(0, i).Value2 = redVar Then
          redVarCount = redVarCount + 1
          Exit For
        ElseIf r.Offset(0, i).Value2 = amberVar And Not amberFound Then
          amberVarCount = amberVarCount + 1
          amberFound = True
        ElseIf r.Offset(0, i).Value2 = greenVar And Not amberFound And Not greenFound Then
          greenVarCount = greenVarCount + 1
          greenFound = True
        End If
      Next i
    Next r

    Range("DO22").Value = redVarCount
    Range("DO23").Value = amberVarCount
    Range("DO24").Value = greenVarCount
  End If
End Sub
```

**Results**
[image]

Comment: If there is a better way to do this then I would appreciate the help.  I have some data to the question.I cant understand how to reach the goal I want to get. I need to check row by row and see if the value red appears 1 of the 3 cells if it does add a count to red, if not nxt check amber if yes add a count to amber, other wise add count for green.  This needs to happen for each row within the range of mediums. - I hope that makes sense and you can understand what it is I am trying to achieve

Comment: @user3088476 You only want one count added to "red", even if there are multiple "reds" in each row?

Comment: yes that is correct only one count to be added to red even if multiple occurrences in the row, if no occurrence then check for amber and only one count to be added the amber count even if multiple occurrence.

Comment: No counts added to amber if "red" is already found? @user3088476

Comment: yes that's right, if a red occurrence has been found then no counts to be added to amber or green just add count to red and move on to the next row in the range. if no red but an amber then only add the count to the amber and not the red or green.  Same applies for the green count, if no occurrences of red or amber only add to green count

Comment: Thanks for that, I have copied your code over, but it doesn't seem to do anything.  I compiles ok but when I run I get no results at all printed on the screen and no message box

Comment: That means it hasn't entered the enclosing if-statement, which again means that the first find hasn't found a range containing "medium" in column H. I'd advice you to check if your range and worksheet references are correct.  @user3088476

Comment: there was a typo in it from when I copied it over I think, it now enters the if statement, does some counting, but I don't get the results I was expecting.  I don't a manual count and on my proper web page there is 47 Greens, 4 Ambers and 0 reds for the medium range.  but the results I am getting when running the code is Red 0 Amber 5 green 1

Comment: Check the spelling of "Red Variance" in the macro / on your sheet? It's hard to tell for certain without seeing your data. And doublecheck that all ranges refer to what you think they refer to. If none of the data is confidential, try posting the contents of it to a google-sheet, and I'll see if I can spot anything obvious. @user3088476

Comment: ive checked the spellings etc and I cant see any other typos and I think all the range are correct.  So not sure exactly why is it isn't working correctly.  unfortunately I cant post my data as the info is confidential. - thanks for all the help you have given so far,

Comment: I have written a small if (countIf statement which I know works on a single cell : - '=IF(COUNTIF(AS22:AU22,"red Variance")>0,"red Variance",IF(COUNTIF(AS22:AU22,"amber Variance")>0,"amber Variance","green"))' So I have tried putting this in the vb code using this infront : - ' Range("DO22:DO" & lastRow).formula ' but get a compile error, I would also need to change the cells in the if count as I wont always knot the start and end cell this will be found running the bit of code from earlier. the mediumStart and mediumEnd  Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: @user3088476 I'm a bit preoccupied right now, but if you're not in too much of a hurry,  I'll try to have a look at it again tomorrow.

Comment: Thank would be a great help if you didn't mind doing that.  Im at a loss really as to why It wont work.